# how to print "" without single space in soap request in jax-ws

Tags: java, web-services, soap

```
SOAPElement soapElement = soapbodyElement.addChildElement(new QName(  
                "", "sPassword"));
```

i am using the above code to make a node to print

```
<sPassword xmlns="">string</sPassword>
```

but instead it prints

```
<sPassword>string</sPassword>
```

is there any way please help
stuck on this since 1 day.
i dont want to read xml file

Comment: What is the difference between what you want and what you're getting? According to your question they are both the same. Please clarify.

Comment: i am consuming webservice in which xlmns="" (without space b/w quotes) it only takes this format but when i use the above code it prints last one